# Compatibility between D-Link Media Converter Chassis and TRENDnet Media Converter Chassis

Tags: networking, hardware

I am working on an experimental networking project. This project will involve a number of twisted-pair to fiber optic media converters.

Due to the number of converters we will be using, we are looking at a common chassis that are meant to hold a number of these converters.

We are looking at a couple of models for the chassis: The D-Link [DMC-1000](http://www.dlink.com/ca/en/business-solutions/switching/network-and-switch-accessories/nic-cards-and-media-converters/dmc-1000-chassis-system-for-dmc-series-media-converters) and the TrendNet [TFC-1600](http://www.trendnet.com/langen/products/proddetail.asp?prod=100_TFC-1600&cat=132). Of course, each chassis has a complete line of network media converters that are meant to be installed in it.

However, it didn't take long to notice how similar the chassis and converters from both D-Link and TrendNet appear. Aside from logos and the like, they seem almost identical.

Does anyone out there know if a D-Link network converter will work in a TrendNet chassis, or vice-versa? Are they part of some standard?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although that *physical* chassis is identical, in fact I've see that part used on other things too, there's no way to know if it'll be *electrically/electronically* compatible. Certainly neither supplier will commit to interoperability, it's not in their commercial interest.

I think it prudent to assume they're not compatible, anything else could prove costly.

Comment: I agree, the prudent answer is that they are NOT compatible, but the similarities go beyond just the first-glance appearance of the chassis themselves. They boast the same features (redundant power, optional management unit), and close examination seems to show that even the status LEDs are in the same locations ( although the images aren't always clear ).

Answer (score 1):

We went ahead and ordered the parts, and could get an eve closer look at them once they arrived. The pin-outs on the card edge were the same (allowing for different features on the different media converter cards).

So, we decided to chance it. (I know, not the most *prudent* thing to do. In fact, it might have been down right dumb).

Anyway, it turns out the TrendNET TFC-1600 can take the D-Link DMC-1000 cards just fine. The management console even recognized the cards capabilities, and can change the cards settings. (Although it didn't get the brand name or exact model number)

Now, that being said, I wouldn't recommend people run out and buy different products and just try mixing and mashing them. We took a chance, and it paid off. This might not work for everyone. Don't try unless you check the pinouts *very* carefully, and don't mind taking the risk.
In other words, try at your own risk.

Comment: Marked Chopper3's reply as the answer, as it is the safer course of action.